# Laptop bluescreens in ntfs.sys and fltmgr.sys

Tags: windows-7, windows, reboot

I have a Lenovo Y510P and it show random blue screens. This is on Windows 7 64bit SP1 CZ Home Edition.

I bought this notebook two years ago with 6GB RAM and recently upgraded to 16GB.

I don't know If there is any connection between frequent crashes and websites in my browsers (Opera, Chrome) or programs like NetBeans. And I work with Windows 7 64bit in VirtualBox, too.

First blue screen:

[image]

Second blue screen:

[image]

Comment: You have not provided enough information to help

Comment: Have you installed anything lately?  What was the last thing you were doing before it happened?....

Comment: Thanks. I added the informations to my description. I install Ram before 2 weeks.

Comment: boot off a memtest86 disk and run the memory tests for long times. that will not only test your newly installed memory, but might explain  one of the bsods shown.

Comment: run **chkdsk /f** to detect NTFS issues if memtest86+ shows no issues

Answer (score 2):

Both of your crashes are in filesystem drivers - ntfs.sys and fltmgr.sys. This could be a coincidence, but it hints at a problem in the storage subsystem.

The first thing I'd do is look at the SMART data to see if your hard drive is failing. A tool for this is [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html). If the health status is anything but good, you found your problem. You need to back up your data ASAP (particularly: don't use the computer for anything else - the longer you use a failing drive, the more likely you are to not get your data off before it dies entirely).

If SMART is in good shape, the next thing to do would be to run Memtest86 and ensure your memory is good. Failures can come suddenly, and you said you just did an upgrade. Let this run overnight *at least*. Any failures in memtest, even one, are grounds to write off the memory as bad.

If that gets you nothing, check to see if the drivers for your SATA controllers are up to date. You'd need to look at Lenovo's website and see if they have newer drivers available.

Barring all this, my thoughts go towards hardware problems, and laptops are not known to be user friendly to work on. If you got this far and it's still flaky, the next thing you should do is call Lenovo.

Good luck!

Comment: I was about to say something similar ;)

Comment: Thanks for ideas, i tried them.

But the result of scan "checkdisk /f C:" was 0 errors. Same result was with "memtest86". Result of SMART is that HDD is in good state. And drivers are latest installed.

Can be this problem with SW or OS? Or this is problem only with HW?

Comment: chkdsk won't tell you if your SMART has found disk trouble - you really need to download a third party tool like CrystalDisk to find that out. Also, this is going to sound silly, but try pulling out the RAM you just installed and run on the original sticks - just to see if the problem still happens.